# Bash find a number and add content

Tags: bash, scripting

i try to write a script that inserts 4 rows into a file. 
I had to add the new text between two numbers.

Example:
I had to add the number 12345 between 12340 and 12348...

I try to work with the rows number like that:

```
newpartnerID = $partnerid

while [[ $schleifeende != "Ende" ]]

do
    if [[ $(grep -Eo "$newpartnerID" text.txt; echo $?) -eq 1 ]]
     then
         let newpartnerID=$newpartnerID+1
     else
         schleifeende="Ende"
         countID=$(grep -n "$newpartnerID" text.txt | cut -f1 -d:)
         let countIDnew=${countID}-1
     fi
done
```

but that doesn't work :D

Do u know a better and simplyer solution for that task?

Comment: Site note: The mixing of English and German variable names is super ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be more specific with grep, for example suppose your new partner id was just 1234.  It would match your pre-existing lines with 12340 and 12348 and so would not be included.

File manipulation of this sort is probably better done with other tools than just bash, like awk and/or sed, as provided below.

It appears your file is of the format and in order such that a partnerid1 is less than a partnerid2 and each of the associated rows:

```
partnerid1:some text
line1 for partnerid1
line2 for partnerid1
line3 for partnerid1
line4 for partnerid1
partnerid2:some other text
line1 for partnerid2
line2 for partnerid2
line3 for partnerid2
line4 for partnerid4
```

Assuming above ordered file, you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

partnerid=`head -1 $1 | cut -f1 -d:`
partnerrows=`wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}'`

# find insert point
FN=text.txt
NEWFN=new.text.txt
Linenumber=`cat $FN | awk -v partnerid=$partnerid -v partnerdata=$1 -v rowcount=$partnerrows '
    BEGIN {
        partnerid = partnerid + 0
        INRANGE=0
        inserthere=0
    }
    /^[0-9]+:/ {
            sub(/\:.*/,"")
            id = $0 + 0
            if (partnerid == id) {
                inserthere = -1
                exit
            }
            # if not in range, check if it is now
            if (INRANGE == 0) {
                if (partnerid > id) {
                    INRANGE = 1
                    inserthere = NR + rowcount - 1
                }
            }
            # if in range and this id now less, then have our location
            if (INRANGE == 1) {
                inserthere = NR + rowcount - 1
                if (partnerid < id) {
                    inserthere = NR -1
                    exit
                }
            }
        }
    END {
        print inserthere
    }
'`

FNLEN=`wc -l $FN | awk '{print $1}'`
rm -f $NEWFN
touch $NEWFN
if [ $Linenumber -gt 0 ]; then
    cat $FN | sed -n "1,${Linenumber}p" >> $NEWFN
fi
if [ $Linenumber -ge 0 ]; then
    cat $1 >> $NEWFN
fi
if [ $Linenumber -ge 0 -a $Linenumber -le $FNLEN ]; then
    Linenumber=$((Linenumber + 1))
    cat $FN | sed -n "${Linenumber},\$p" >> $NEWFN
fi
```